# How to convert byte into Boolean

Tags: c#

I want to convert a byte into Boolean. This is the code:

```
String text = textBox1.Text;
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text,8899);
IPEndPoint ep = null;

while (true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
    string name = "Connected";
    if (name == "") break;

    byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
    udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);

    if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)=null)
    {
      //  MessageBox.Show("Host not found");
    }
    else
    {        
        byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
        string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
        MessageBox.Show(job);
    }
}
```

I want to convert this line of code into a Boolean:

```
  udpc.Receive(ref ep);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want true or false value returned wether the Host is found or not?

Comment: Use the comparison operator `==`

Comment: if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)=null)

Comment: Without really knowing what you are trying to do, I would assume that you want to change this: "if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)=null)" to "if (udpc.Receive(ref ep) == null)". = is assignment operator, while == is equality operator.

Comment: Why do you want to convert an array of bytes into a boolean value?

Comment: thank you comparison operator helped  me to solved it

Comment: @Derek I'm guessing because the compiler error when you use assignment instead of comparison is "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to type 'bool'`"

Comment: @user1713389: No, please see my answer - currently you'd be skipping every other packet.

Comment: @user1713389: Also, please take more care over your formatting for future questions - there's no reason to have a blank line between each real line of code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to just compare the result with null at all... that way you would lose the actual data, and then call `Receive` again, effectively skipping the packet.

You should use:

```
byte[] data = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
if (data == null)
{
    // Whatever
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
}
```

Also note that this code is broken:

```
string name = "Connected";
if (name == "") break;
```

How can `name` possibly be an empty string when you've just set it to `"Connected"`?

Answer (score 0):

The `UdpClient` is naturally blocking until bytes are received.

This means that you shouldn't get data at all, assuming that you're looking for a way to indicate if you have received data, then once you move past the `udpc.Recieve`, you should return true.

I would also consider changing the code a bit as you will have some compilation issues with the `= null` statement as this does not translate into a compilable code expression.

There is also a problem with your if else statement as you're attempting to read from the UDP client which would consume the sent data.

Personally I would opt for a UDP socket, but in order to get you rolling I would change the code to something like this:

```
String text = textBox1.Text;
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text,8899);
IPEndPoint ep = null;

while (true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
    string name = "Connected";
    if (name == "") break; //This will never happen because you have already set the value
    byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
    int dataSent = 0;
    try
    {
        dataSent = udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        dataSent = 0;
        //There is an exception. Probably the host is wrong
    }
    if (dataSent > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            if(rdata!=null && rdata.Length > 0)
            {
                string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
                MessageBox.Show(job)
                //True here as we managed to recieve without going to the catch statement
                //and we actually have data in the byte[]
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("We did not recieve any data");
                //False here, because the array was empty.
            }
        }
        catch(Exception udpe)
        {
            //False here as we had a socket exception or timed out
            MessageBox.Show(udpe.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```